# Joint two datasets under restrictions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset

I want to joint two different datasets according to month and year. Each one of them has 3 columns, one is the year, one is the month and the last one is averages of two different things. The first dataset has years 2010 and 2011 and the second one 2015 and 2016. I want to make a third dataset where I will have the average of June 2010 in one column and the average of October 2015 in another column. In other words, I want to connect two different years and different months. I want it to look like that:

| Year | Month | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | October | 15.7 |
| 2010 | November | 13.6 |
| 2010 | December | 13.9 |

| Year | Month | AVG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | June | 18.2 |
| 2015 | July | 18.4 |
| 2015 | August | 19.0 |

| Year2 | Month2 | Year1 | Month1 | AVG2 | AVG1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | June | 2010 | October | 18.2 | 15.7 |
| 2015 | July | 2010 | November | 18.4 | 13.6 |
| 2015 | August | 2010 | December | 19.0 | 13.9 |

Part of the dataset 1 looks like that:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010), Month = c("April", "August", "December", "February", 
"January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November"), Log_AVG = c(4.95582705760126, 4.86753445045558, 
5.34233425196481, 5.35185813347607, 5.33753807970132, 4.82028156560504, 
4.69134788222914, 5.29831736654804, 4.75359019110636, 5.12989871492307
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
    2010, 2010), Month = c("April", "August", "December", "February", 
    "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November"), .rows = structure(list(
        1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And part of the second dataset looks like that:

```
structure(list(Year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015), Month = structure(1:10, .Label = c("January", "February", 
"March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
"October", "November", "December"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), Log_AVG = c(0, 0, 9.08398318309966, 8.76029622047005, 
7.13089883029635, 7.07834157955767, 7.95892649305011, 8.8146275553107, 
9.69572510326022, 10.5731101880491)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
     Year = 2015, .rows = structure(list(
        1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Is there any way that I can do that with R?
Or is there any way to order the two initial datasets in the way that I like (for example leave the one as it is, and order the second one according to month but not alphabetical, having June of 2015 as the first month and continue with the rest months of 2015 and 2016)?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: As you are not arranging your data in a particular way, just rename your columns and combine both dataframes with `cbind()` or `dplyr::bind_cols()`.

Comment: That works thank you. One more question though. In the one dataset I have, the months are not in the correct order I want them to be. I used spread to create that dataset which makes the months be in alphabetical order, which doesn't work for me. Is there any way that I can re-order this dataset in the way that I want? To start from June and then have all the rest months in the correct order (June, July, August ...)? Thanks a lot

Comment: Use the built-in `month.name` object that has the month names in the right order. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21316341/903061).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want fixed offsets where the "date2" is 5 years and 4 months ahead of "date1", I'd make that computation. Something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
  mutate(
    date1 = ymd(paste(Year, Month, "01")),
    date2 = date1 + years(5) + months(4)
  ) %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>% mutate(date2 = ymd(paste(Year, Month, "01"))),
    by = "date2",
    suffix = c("1", "2")
  )
```

If you share data in a copy/pasteable format I'll happily test and debug.

Comment: I just uploaded part of the two datasets. Thank you so much!

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you just want cbind to put the two data frames next to each other:

```
d1<-data.frame(Year=rep(2010,3),
               Month = c("October","November","December"),
               AVG=c(15.7,13.6,13.9))
d2<-data.frame(Year=rep(2015,3),
               Month = c("June","July","August"),
               AVG=c(15.7,13.6,13.9))
d3<-cbind(d1,d2)
```

which gives us:

```
> d1
  Year    Month  AVG
1 2010  October 15.7
2 2010 November 13.6
3 2010 December 13.9
> d2
  Year  Month  AVG
1 2015   June 15.7
2 2015   July 13.6
3 2015 August 13.9
> d3<-cbind(d1,d2)
> d3
  Year    Month  AVG Year  Month  AVG
1 2010  October 15.7 2015   June 15.7
2 2010 November 13.6 2015   July 13.6
3 2010 December 13.9 2015 August 13.9
```

If you have to sort by month then first you need to convert to a factor of `month.name` like this:

```
d4<-data.frame(Year=rep(2010,3),
                   Month = c("November","December","October"),
                   AVG=c(13.6,13.9,15.7))
d4$Month <- factor(d4$Month, levels = month.name)
d4 <- d4[order(d4$Month),]
```

which gives us this:

```
> d4
  Year    Month  AVG
1 2010 November 13.6
2 2010 December 13.9
3 2010  October 15.7
> d4$Month <- factor(d4$Month, levels = month.name)
> d4 <- d4[order(d4$Month),]
> d4
  Year    Month  AVG
3 2010  October 15.7
1 2010 November 13.6
2 2010 December 13.9
```

Comment: Thank you so much!